# Yii2 disable field

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii2, field, disabled-input

In yii2 I have two fields (Text1 and Text2). I want to disable the second field (Text2) if the first field (Text1) is not null.
I think this can be done with javascript but I dont't really know.
Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>

var textbox1 = document.getElementById("id1");
    textbox1.onkeyup = function(){
    value = document.getElementById("id1").value;
    if(value.length != 0){
     document.getElementById("id2").disabled = true;
    }
    else {
      document.getElementById("id2").disabled = false;
    }
 };

<script>
```

Comment: I replaced id1 with Text1 and id2 with Text2. Was this wrong? Because unfortunatly ist does'nt work...

Comment: can you show your html and javascript code related to this?

Comment: Your code was right and worked for me now.    
I only had to write the tablename before Text1.  
<script>
var textbox1 = document.getElementById("tablename-Text1");
    textbox1.onkeyup = function(){
    value = document.getElementById("tablename-Text1").value;
    if(value.length != 0){
     document.getElementById("tablename-Text2").disabled = true;
    }
    else {
      document.getElementById("tablename-Text2").disabled = false;
    }
 };
<script>

  
Thanks a lot!